# Is it currently possible to programmatically enable iap.googleapis.com in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, identity-aware-proxy

Is it currently possible to programmatically enable iap.googleapis.com in GCP?

When we configure the iap service in terraform currently, it doesnt seem to be fully enabled.

When I visit the IAP page in gcp console, it tells me:

"Before you can use IAP, you need to configure your OAuth consent screen."

Terraform doesnt seem to have an option for changing this - is there an api we could invoke manually, or are we not able to automate this part?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIRC it's not possible to programmatically enable OAuth consent so I think the problem isn't that you can't programmatically enable the service (you can) but it has a dependency that can only be enabled by a human.

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks like this is possible. When you enable the api, it does display that warning, but you can still create iap resources, and the iap brand.

However you can only create internal iap resources by default.